# iOS - RIghtbarbutton exists but not visible

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to add a rightBarButtonItem to the navigationitem.But whatever I do I can not see the button on the navigation bar. If I NSLog for self.navigationItem.title I get the right title.And also if I NSLog the rightBarButtonItem I get the barbutton item's memory locatioin, so not null. Here's how I add my bar button item:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:......];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barButton;
```

What should I do to make the button visible on the navigation bar.

EDIT: Here's the ViewCOntroller hierarchy:

MechViewController//This gets pushed to the navigation stack

PageViewController//This is created in the MechViewController viewDidLoad method and added as a childViewController

PhotoViewController//This is view controller that I add to the PageViewController's viewControllers array. This is where I need to add bar button item and specify its action.

Comment: WHat do you by screens? This is the only part of the code that involves adding a bar button item.

Comment: And also, I tried adding the above code right after pushing the view controller to the navigation stack and I got the button displayed. But I need to do it on a child view controller.

Comment: When you creating `PhotoViewController`-instance in `PageViewController`, try to write `instance.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the button in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  IBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:......];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
  [barButton release];
}
```

Comment: Try an autorelease. Not release.